# Haskell - simple way to cache a function call

Tags: performance, haskell

I have functions like:

```
millionsOfCombinations = [[a, b, c, d] | 
  a <- filter (...some filter...) someListOfAs, 
  b <- (...some other filter...) someListOfBs, 
  c <- someListOfCs, d <- someListOfDs]

aLotOfCombinationsOfCombinations = [[comb1, comb2, comb3] | 
  comb1 <- millionsOfCombinations, 
  comb2 <- millionsOfCombinations,
  comb3 <- someList,
  ...around 10 function calls to find if
    [comb1, comb2, comb3] is actually useful]
```

Evaluating `millionsOfCombinations` takes 40s. on a very fast workstation. Evaluating `aLotOfCombinationsOfCombinations`!!0 took 2 days :-(

How can I speed up this code? So far I've had 2 ideas - use a profiler. Tried running `myapp +RTS -sstderr` after compiling with GHC, but get a blank screen and don't want to wait days for it to finish.

2nd thought was to somehow cache `millionsOfCombinations`. Do I understand correctly that for each value in `aLotOfCombinationsOfCombinations`, `millionsOfCombinations` gets evaluated multiple times? If that is so, how can I cache the result? Obviously I've just started learning Haskell. I know there is a way to do call caching with a monad, but I still don't understand those things.

Comment: Do you understand 'caching' ([memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)) in a language other than Haskell? If so, then this [explanation](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization) may be helpful for you.

Comment: Please provide some more details on the algorithm. You say you want to cache `millionsOfCombinations`, but this is already a list, so there shouldn't be any recomputation (see the list approach to Fibonnaci calculations at http://goo.gl/YgV7b ). What's the space of things that are useful? (i.e. how often does the filter remove things?) What's the memory usage?

Comment: OK, so I don't need to manually add cashing. In that case `millionsOfCombinations` is probably not the problem. Any ideas on how to optimize the second method? Very few of the combinations are useful, maybe 1 in 300 000. It uses around 70MB while running. From the GHC profiler statistics, it seems there are a lot garbage collections - hundreds of thousands in a few minutes.

Comment: The garbage may have to do with the list construction; I think the vector or array classes might be more efficient. I'm also not sure if what's inside the list comprehension is cached, namely the "a <- filter ... someListOfAs". Maybe try putting it ouside. If e.g. the list of b's is not dependent on which _a_ you have selected, then you might want to cache these iteration lists (assign them to variables). That is, "aList = filter ... someListOfAs", then in the comprehension, "a <- aList".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use the `-fforce-recomp`, `-O2` and `-fllvm` flags**

If you aren't already, be sure to use the above flags.  I wouldn't normally mention it, but I've seen some questions recently that didn't know powerful optimization isn't a default.

**Profile Your Code**

The `-sstderr` flag isn't exactly profiling.  When people say profiling they're usually talking about either heap profiling or time profiling via [`-prof` and `-auto-all`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/prof-compiler-options.html) flags.

**Avoid Costly Primitives**

If you need the entire list in memory (i.e. it isn't going to be optimized away) then consider unboxed vectors.  If `Int` will do instead of `Integer`, consider that (but Integer is a reasonable default when you don't know!).  Use worker/wrapping transforms at the right times.  If you're leaning heavily on `Data.Map`, try using `Data.HashMap` from the unordered-containers library.  This list can go on and on, but since you don't already have an intuition on where your computation time is going the profiling should come first!

Answer (score 3):

I think, that there is no way. Please notice, that the time to generate the list is growing with each list involved. So you get around 1000000<sup>3</sup> combinations to check, which indeed takes a lot of time. Caching the list ist possible but is unlikely to change anything, since new elements can be generated almost instantly. The only way is probably to change the algorithm.

If `millionsOfCombinations` is a constant (and not a function with arguments), it is cached automatically. Else, make it a constant by using a where clause:

```
aLotOfCombinationsOfCombinations = [[comb1, comb2, comb3] | 
  comb1 <- millionsOfCombinations, 
  comb2 <- millionsOfCombinations,
  comb3 <- someList,
  ...around 10 function calls to find if
    [comb1, comb2, comb3] is actually useful] where

  millionsOfCombinations = makeCombination xyz
```

Comment: But if calling `millionsOfCombinations` goes from 40s to 1ns, that would speed up every possible element of `aLotOfCombinationsOfCombinations` with 80s. Plus I know the algorithm can work a lot faster, it's my naive implementation that is slow.